# MVC 3 the url's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I m creating Web application using MVC3.In Global.asax we are giving the routings like below.

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Login", action = "RedirectToLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Paging",
        "Home/Page/{page}",
           new { controller = "Login", action = "RedirectToLogin" }
       );


    }
```

After this in Login page we are giving ~ symbol to access the css,js files like below.

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And other aspx pages we are access the css,js files like below

```
 <link href="<%= Url.Content("../Content/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery.mobile.min.js")%>"></script>
```

**ADDED**

I am using common toast message for all pages.At that time

```
        if (messageType == "notification") { 
            $.mobile.loading("show", {
                text: message,
                textVisible: true,
                theme: "b",
                textonly: false,
                html: "<span></span><img src='../Content/jquery.mobile/images/notice.png' style='margin-left:75px'><h1>" + message + "</h1>"
            });
```

While accessing the image in different page creating problem.
            }

Url accessing is different between the pages.Is there any way to make it common for all pages.Please suggest the solution for this

Comment: Please add your code as text. It is hardly readable now. Also, what is wrong with the `~` you used before?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have changed my question.

Comment: I see, thanks for that. Can you answer my second question about the use of `~`?

Comment: To get the files for current url

Comment: But why doesn't `~` work? Can you give an example?

Comment: ~ is not working with other page because it taking the controller name which we given in the global.asax that is what in other page if we are giving ~ it wont work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51582/discussion-between-kanna-and-patrick-hofman)